# Restrict API endpoint by total requests of each user

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently exploring solutions to limit access to an API endpoint on NodeJS by total number of requests per month.

For instance, I want the free plan users to access the `/api` endpoint up to a total of 100 requests per month, and the premium plan users to have 5000 requests per month.

The naïve way to get around it is by implementing a passport middleware to get the user's plan and then keep track of the count:

```
  app.get("/api", requireAuth, async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        // Check if user ran out of requests
        if (req.user.apiRequestsLeft === 0) {
          res.send("You ran out of API requests!")
        } else {
          // Decrement the allocated requests
          req.user.apiRequestsLeft--;
          await req.user.save();
          res.send(user)
        }
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  });
```

My concerns are:

1. Performance/Scalability issues of having to update a MongoDB document each time there's a request - is this feasible or will I hit a problem when the app grows?
2. Resetting the count - should this be a daily cronjob that looks at the timestamp of 'registration' of each and every user, compute if a month has passed and reset allotted requests accordingly, or is there a better way of designing something like this?

Comment: 1. req.user -> make that "_id" in mongodb so it is easy to search and load issue won't be there.
2. Don't use daily cron job. Instead add a field in mongodb that checks for date and compares it with 1 month everytime request comes.

I am too curious to know if there is better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Performance/Scalability issues of having to update a MongoDB document
>   each time there's a request - is this feasible or will I hit a problem
>   when the app grows?

Definitely. You will soon experience heavy mongoDB traffic and it will hit performance bottleneck.  In my opinion, you should use a faster in-memory database like [Redis](https://redis.io/) to handle the situation. You can even use the Redis as the `session-store` which will reduce the load on MongoDB. That way, MongoDB can be utilized for other Business queries.

> Resetting the count - should this be a daily cronjob that looks at the
>   timestamp of 'registration' of each and every user, compute if a month
>   has passed and reset allotted requests accordingly, or is there a
>   better way of designing something like this?

A better way would be to achieve the resetting part in the middleware itself.

Here is some code that explains my solution.

Sample design of `Quota` object would be:

```
{
    type: "FREE_USER",                  /** or "PREMIUM_USER" */
    access_limit: 100,                  /** or 5000 */
    exhausted_requests: 42              /** How many requests the user has made so far this month */
    last_reset_timestamp: 1547796508728 /** When was the exhausted_requests set to 0 last time */
}
```

With that design. Your middleware that checks the quota would look something like:

```
const checkQuota = async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = req.user;
    const userQuotaStr = await redis.getAsync(user.id)
    let userQuota;
    /** Check if we have quota information about user */
    if (userQuotaStr != null) {
        /** We have previously saved quota information */
        userQuota = JSON.parse(userQuotaStr);

        /** 
         * Check if we should reset the exhausted_requests
         * Assuming that all the requests are reset on the First Day of each month.
         */
        if ( isStartOfMonth() ) {
            /** 
             * It is First Day of the month. We might need to reset the `exhausted_requests` 
             * Check the difference between `Date.now()` and `userQuota.last_reset_timestamp`
             * to determine whether we should reset or not
             */
            if ( shouldResetTimeStamp(userQuota.last_reset_timestamp) ) {
                userQuota.exhausted_requests = 0
                userQuota.last_reset_timestamp = Date.now()
            }
        }
    } else {
        /** We do not have previously saved quota information. Prepare one */
        userQuota = {
            type: user.type,
            access_limit: user.access_limit,
            exhausted_requests: 0,
            last_reset_timestamp: Date.now()
        }
    }

    /** Incredement the counter to account the current request */
    userQuota.exhausted_requests++

    /** Update in database */
    redis.set(user.id, JSON.stringify(userQuota))


    if ( userQuota.exhausted_requests >= userQuota.access_limit ) {
        /** User has reached the quota limit. Deny the request. set with 401 or 403 status code */
    } else {
        /** User can access the API. call next() */
    }   
}
```

Of course, the snippet is is incomplete. It just gives you the idea about how to go about writing that middleware.

Here is how you can use the middleware for your APIs:

```
/** If requests to routes are under the quota */
app.get("/api/quota-routes", requireAuth, checkQuota, /** Mount the actual middleware here */)

/** If requests to routes are unlimited, just remove the checkQuota middleware */
app.get("/api/unlimited-routes", requireAuth, /** Mount the actual middleware here */)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer - what strategy do you consequently use to save the quota object to the db? Do you have another hourly cronjob that syncs with the db or something?

Comment: Yes you can have a CRON running to sync. Be careful with CRON though, by the nature of it, it tends to read-write database a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[rate-limiter-flexible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limiter-flexible) package helps with counters and automatically expire counters.

```
const opts = {
  storeClient: mongoConn,
  points: 5000, // Number of points
  duration: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // Per month
};
const rateLimiterMongo = new RateLimiterMongo(opts);
const rateLimiterMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
   // req.userId should be set before this middleware
   const key = req.userId ? req.userId : req.ip;
   const pointsToConsume = req.userId ? 1 : 50;
   rateLimiterMongo.consume(key, pointsToConsume)
      .then(() => {
          next();
      })
      .catch(_ => {
          res.status(429).send('Too Many Requests');
      });
   };

app.use(rateLimiterMiddleware);
```

Note, this example is not bound to calendar month, but counts events from the first event within the next month after it. You could set custom duration with 
[block](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/API-methods#ratelimiterblockkey-secduration) to strictly connect counters expiry to calendar months.

This code should easily handle about 1k-2k requests per second on basic server. You could also use [Redis limiter](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Redis) or [Mongo limiter with sharding options](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Mongo#mongodb-sharding-options).

Also, it provides [In-memory Block strategy](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Overall-example#apply-in-memory-block-strategy-against-massive-ddos) to avoid too much requests to MongoDB/Redis/any store.

Alternatively, play with [get](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Mongo#mongodb-sharding-options) method from [rate-limiter-flexible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limiter-flexible) to decrease amount of unnecessary counters updates. `get` method is much-much faster than increment.